# Weighted, blended order independent transparency

Tags: opengl, graphics, shader, transparency

I want to use Meshkin method described here http://jcgt.org/published/0002/02/09/paper-lowres.pdf page 5 in order to obtain a basic weighted, blended order independent transparency.

I don't understand who is Ci and ai.
Also, what is "Multiple render targets".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The assumption is that you are rendering a number of "surfaces", indexed by i = 1, ..., n.  Each surface has a color C<sub>i</sub> and an alpha (opacity, or coverage) α<sub>i</sub>.

As for Multiple render targets, you could look it up on Wikipedia, but it's basically multiple buffers you can render to at once.  For instance in OpenGL, a framebuffer object (FBO) can have multiple renderbuffer or texture objects attached to it.

Comment: So does it mean you create multiple framebuffers for each overlapping texture? e.g. player looks through three windows, so there are three FBOs using the shader shown on page 5.

Comment: @FanusduToit: not multiple FBOs, multiple render targets on one FBO.

Comment: @FanManPro no; you only need one additional render buffer in your FBO to accumulate the (weighted) sums of `Ci` and `wi`. (I know this was asked years ago.)